# Runsettings file in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, runsettings

I have some unit tests in my project that needs runsettings file to run properly.

When I launch those tests, I have issues with parameters that should be taken from the runsettings file

My question is how can I pass the runsettings file to visual studio code in order to use it when I execute my tests ?

Thank you in advance,

Regards

Answer (score 3):

Two parts need file `.runsettings` when you work with VS Code:

1. when `build` tests in VS Code, it firstly run `vstest.exe` with parameters
2. when `run` tests in VS Code, it need `mstest.exe`.

For the first part, here is the document for .NET Core Test Explorer:
https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-dotnet-test-explorer

> The settings are available via File / Preferences / Settings. Navigate
> to extensions and .NET Core test explorer.
>
> Additional arguments that are added to the dotnet test command. These
> can for instance be used to collect code coverage data
> ("/p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=lcov
> /p:CoverletOutput=../../lcov.info") or pass test settings
> ("--settings:./myfilename.runSettings")

[image]
But above settings are global, you can setup from `.vscode\workspace.code-workspace` file for specified test project only:

```
{
  "folders": [
    {
      "path": ".."
    }
  ],
  "settings": {
    "dotnet-test-explorer.testArguments": "--settings .runsettings",
    "dotnet-test-explorer.testProjectPath": "**/test.project.name.csproj"
  }
}
```

For the second part, we need a new feature [RunSettingsFilePath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2019#set-a-build-property) that's delivered from VS 2019 16.4.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <RunSettingsFilePath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\.runsettings</RunSettingsFilePath> // or $(SolutionDir)
  </PropertyGroup>
  ...
</Project>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the [C# extension for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp), there's a setting to configure your *.runsettings* file. Go into VS Code's settings and search '.runsettings'. This should show the "Omnisharp: Test Run Setting" setting under the Extensions > C# configuration node.
[image: Test Run Settings setting in VS Code C# configuration]

I suggest clicking on the "Workspace" tab, so the setting is stored in your project instead of your user. That way, you can also check these settings into git.